# Firestore Data Structure for a Shop

Tags: firebase, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore

I've been building a site for selling used materials and I used to have my firestore database as follows

```
Posts(collection)
   ┣ userID1(document)
   ┃   ┣ postID1(collection)
   ┃   ┃   ┗ timestamp: 2018/09/21/22:22(field)
   ┃   ┣ postID2
   ┃   ┗ postID3
   ┣ userID2
   ┣ userID3

AllPosts(collection)
   ┣ allPosts(document)
   ┃   ┣ postID1(collection)
   ┃   ┃   ┗ timestamp: 2018/09/21/22:22(field)
   ┃   ┣ postID2
   ┃   ┗ postID3
```

To load all the posts for the home page, I used to access the AllPosts collection and then get the allPosts document to have all the posts as one read on firestore. Incase the user wants to view one shop materials, I access the Posts collection to have all the user posts.

I then realized that documents got a limit of 1MB and so i can't use one document to store all the posts in a larger scale. So, I have to use one collection called posts with each post presenting a document. Wouldn't result in having so many reads and potentially exceeding firestore reads limit given that all of the posts need to be loaded every time the user opens the app. Am i missing something or is this as efficient as it gets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is fairly idiomatic for cases where you frequently only need a subset of the data.

You could consider sharding the `AllPosts` information over multiple documents, but would need a predictable naming scheme for those. For example, you could base the document ID on the date (and possibly time) of the posts in there, creating an index-document per day (or other relevant time frame).

You could also consider storing the `AllPosts` information in Firebase's Realtime Database, which is more suited to such smaller pieces of information - and doesn't have the cost overhead of document reads. While the Realtime Database is more costly for bandwidth used, that might well be countered by the fact that you have less data per post there. So you'd end up with the `AllPosts` "index" in Realtime Database, and the individual post documents in Firestore.